# output label Y train shape keras tensorflow 1.4

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am running VGG16 network for image classification on svhn database.
I am saving images into shape (None,64,64,3) and labels of shape **(None,10)**.Labels are 1d array of size 10.

Below is the part of my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import scipy
from skimage import data, io, filters
import scipy.io as sio
from utils import *
import h5py

vgg = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16 (include_top=False,
weights='imagenet',
input_tensor=None,
input_shape=(64,64,3),
pooling='avg',
classes=10)

vgg.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='sgd',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

vgg.fit(train_data, labels_data, epochs=5, batch_size=32)
```

and so I get error:

```
    ValueError: Error when checking target: expected block5_pool to have shape (None, 512) but got array with shape (None, 10)
```

What changes should I do?

Comment: What is `weights` tensor? Please post all the required code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: it is 'imagenet'. well i am taking (None, 512) shaped labels to pass through, it would be very helpful if you can explain why outputs are not converging to (None,10) .

Comment: Thanks. But I am still getting only 20% accuracy on training. Can you help? I am normalizing and resizing image to 64*64 then feeding them to this Vgg model.

Comment: I also tried image quantisation but it did not improve accuracy.

Comment: Maybe the imagenet weights are not appropriate for svhn problem?

Comment: Nope. Same results with weights =None. Could be a data problem too, some images are disturbing. Have a look at images in 32 shape svhn mat file .

Comment: Also try more connected layers. At this time you just have a single dense layer. You can add some dense layers with relu activation before final layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Keras docs](https://keras.io/applications/#vgg16), when you set `include_top` to `False`, you omit 3 fully connected layers and if you set it to `True`, you need to have 1000 classes with `imagenet` pretrained weights.

So what you need is to attach fully connected layers on top of the vgg network:

```
model = Sequential([vgg, Dense(10), Activation('softmax')])
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='sgd',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

# now check the input/output shapes
print(model.input_shape)
print(model.output_shape)
```